# How to find frame of visible view in scrollview?

Tags: iphone, scrollview

I have one scroll view in which UIView as a subview.Now i added functionality of zooming.

I want to know after zooming that which frame of UIView in scrollview is visible.How to get that frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they do almost the same in [Apple's photoScroller example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html).
At least, there it is a paging scrollview, with a couple of UIViews on it as well and the create 2 sets. 1 set of visible pages (i believe the visible page +1 and -1) and a set of all the other pages.

Not a direct answer, but hope it helps.

Comment: @dks1725 If it didn't work for you, why did you accept the answer?